# Android studio using flavors with <compatible-screens> in the manifest

Tags: android

I have 1 app but I want to make 2 apks (2 android IDs) and distribute it for both handsets and tablets. 
For this, (and for other things as well) I'm using the `flavors` "feature" of Android Studio.

At the same time I need to use [**this**](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution.html) to set the screen size for each apk. According to the `flavor` method, one needs to create the same item twice in two different folders (it's a very simple way of putting it, i know), but what about this case, should I just copy the `AndroidManifest` in both places and set the proper things within the `<compatible-screens>` tags, or how would one approach this ? 
I'm guessing it would work, but I'd like to know what the best practice is. If anyone knows or has tried it before, do let me know please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind I figured it out by myself. I set this code in `build.gradle` for the app

```
//============================
//   Custom manifest merging:
//============================
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.processManifest.doLast {

        def propertyList = variant.productFlavors*.name
        propertyList.add(variant.buildType.name)

        def variantProperties = new Properties()
        propertyList.reverse().each { property ->
            def propFile = "src/${property}/manifest.properties"
            try {
                file(propFile).withReader { reader ->
                    def tmpProps = new Properties()
                    tmpProps.load(reader)
                    variantProperties.putAll(tmpProps)
                }
            } catch (e) {
                println "[${variant.name}] Failed to load ${propFile}"
            }
        }
        println "[${variant.name}] manifest properties: ${variantProperties}"

        copy {
            from("${buildDir}/intermediates/manifests/full") {
                include "${variant.dirName}/AndroidManifest.xml"
            }
            into("${buildDir}/filtered_manifests")
            filter { String line -> line.replaceAll("<compatible-screens(.*)/>", variantProperties.get("compatible-screens", "")) }
            filter { String line -> line.replaceAll("<supports-screens(.*)/>", variantProperties.get("supports-screens", "")) }
        }
    }
    variant.processResources.manifestFile = file("build/filtered_manifests/${variant.dirName}/AndroidManifest.xml")
}
```

And then I created two files under these paths: `src/phone/manifest.properties` and `src/tablet/manifest.properties` with the next contents:

```
compatible-screens=<compatible-screens>\
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />\
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />\
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />\
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />\
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />\
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />\
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />\
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />\
        </compatible-screens>
```

and

```
supports-screens=<supports-screens \
    android:smallScreens="false" \
    android:normalScreens="false" \
    android:largeScreens="true" \
    android:xlargeScreens="true" \
    android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600" />
```

And in the `AndroidManifest.xml` which is unde `src/main/` i placed two empty tags `<supports-screens />` and `<compatible-screens />`

That's it !

Everything is from this link: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/adt-dev/8igxEyihIlc/gk4b8K6ZxNYJ with the small change of the build path folder. Mine was under `${buildDir}/intermediates/manifests/full`.

Answer (score 2):

I can see you found a solution yourself, but it seems to be a VERY hacky solution that dates back from march-2013, so let me introduce the current standard way of doing it. This method uses the google team implemented manifest merger.

**source -> main -> AndroidManifest.xml**

don't do anything special on it, don't add any screen related stuff to it.

**source -> phone -> AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
   package="your.package.name"
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

   <supports-screens
      android:smallScreens="true"
      android:normalScreens="true"
      android:largeScreens="false"
      android:xlargeScreens="false"/>

</manifest>
```

and then **source -> tablet -> AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
   package="your.package.name"
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

   <supports-screens
      android:smallScreens="false"
      android:normalScreens="false"
      android:largeScreens="true"
      android:xlargeScreens="true"/>

</manifest>
```

Those above are the complete files, just `support-screens` and nothing more. They get merged into your **main -> ANdroidManifest.xml** by the build system.

Also if you want (you'll need for Google Play) to put different version numbers for each of them, in the `build.gradle` inside the `android {` part include:

```
   productFlavors {
        phone {
            versionCode 200001
        }
        tablet {
            versionCode 300001
        }
    }
```

Comment: i have just one flavor 'phone' and this does not work for me. it still does not force the screen compatibility mode on tablets. any ideas?